# SELinux and samba

Tags: fedora, samba, selinux

I have to set SELinux `setenforce Permissive` in order to give access to my samba share. I wonder if there is proper way to configure SELinux policy for fedora 17 as good admins do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need to use `setsebool` which will tell selinux to allow certain activities.

but first do this:

```
/usr/sbin/getsebool -a | grep samba
```

to see if selinux is already allowing samba activity.

if it isn't, here are some examples of what i would use (if i used selinux):

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dir on
/usr/sbin/setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
```

or something comparable depending on what your goal is with how strict you are trying to make it

alternatively you can use `system-config-selinux` and check the options pertaining to samba

Comment: Thanks a lot! i go mark as Solved. just a remark when i tried from terminal #/usr/sbin/setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
 i got libsemanage.semanage_get_lock: Could not get direct transaction lock at /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/semanage.trans.LOCK. (Resource temporarily unavailable).
Could not change policy booleans. And finally i get wanted result with gui app /usr/bin/selinux-polgengui 
where i added a rule for just the same boolean as you advised me